# REACT Uncaught TypeError: x.method() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror

I have this code which creates a Player component which contains the setSpell method inside.

```
class Player extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.setSpell = this.setSpell.bind(this);

        this.state = {

            name: (props.name === undefined) ? 'Tom Default' : props.name,
            speed: 0,
            power: 0,
            health: 100,
            spells: [],

        };

    }//end constructor

    setSpell (spell) {
        let newSpellsArray = this.state.spells.slice();    
        newSpellsArray.push(spell);   
        this.setState({spells: newSpellsArray});
    }
```

In a different functional component, i write

function match() {

```
const [player1, setPlayer1] = useState(props.p1); where props.p1 is p1=<Player /> component
```

the error is thrown when i try to call

```
player1.setSpell('spell');
```

it gives me Uncaught TypeError: player1.setSpell is not a function. How would i fix this error?

```
function Match(props) {

    const [player1, setPlayer1] = useState(props.p1);
    const [player2, setPlayer2] = useState(props.p2);

    const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(false);
    const [turnCount, setTurnCount] = useState(0);
 

    useEffect(() => {
        const spell_archive = ['carmelo dragon','frog knight','thunder cloud','poison breath','ooze','refrigerator ice cube soldier'];

        if (isOn) {
            
            setTurnCount(turnCount+1);

            //draw phase
            if (turnCount===1){
                console.log(player1.props.spells);

                player1.setSpell(randomSpell(spell_archive)); HERE IS THE ISSUE!!!
            }

            setIsOn(false);
        }
    }, [isOn, turnCount, player1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, when you use Class-based components in JSX inside a tag like `<Component />`, it's not same thing as when you declare them as a class. So, you can't call Class-based Components' methods or properties via dot notation `(.)`, what you can do with normal classes in JavaScript.

In your case I can suggest passing only a method(s) as a props, but not whole component and then you can refer to this component method(s) or properties inside a child component via child component' `props` object.

Or, if you really want to use dot notation `(.)`, you can try to do something like this and define your method with `static` keyword:

`static setSpell (spell) {...}`

or even referring to whole component, but in this fashion:

```
const App = () => (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item>Home</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Blog</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>About</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);
```

Please refer: [React Component with Dot Notation](https://medium.com/risan/react-component-with-dot-notation-7a9853dbf33b)

Also you may be interested in `React Context API`, which provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level. [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)